# Navigating autocomplete entries in XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

Sometimes when I type certain words, XCode will offer to autocomplete with several options. If I press enter, it automatically puts the curser on the first option and selects it so when I start typing that part gets replaced. After that, how do I immediately get to the next option, without having to double click it?

For example, if I type the following:

> UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView
>   alloc] ini

Then Xcode offers to autocomplete with the following:

> UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView
>   alloc] initWithTitle:**(NSString
>   *)title** message:**(NSString *)message** delegate:**(id)delegate** cancelButtonTitle:**(NSString
>   *)cancelButtonTitle** otherButtonTitles:**(NSString
>   *)otherButtonTitles**

Everything that appears above in bold is highlighted, meaning they are to be replaced by the programmer. If I press enter to accept the autocomplete, Xcode will put in the above code, and select the first highlighted item, which is **(NSString *)title**. If I start typing something, this is immediately replaced by what I type. When I'm done replacing this, I want to move directly to replacing the next highlighted item, which in this case is **(NSString *)message**. I can do that by double clicking on it, but is there some kind of keyboard shortcut that will get me directly there?

Comment: I updated my answer with the actual answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

Or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter the list of completions.

---

Edit: Aha! Now I know what you mean. You want <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Press the TAB key to move to the next highlighted item and SHIFT + TAB to move backwards through the same list.